# How $x_n=C_1+C_2(-\frac{1}{2})^n $ comes?

Tags: real-analysis

$$ \ln a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(\ln a_n +\ln a_{n+1}) $$

let $ x_n=\ln a_n $, we have

$$ x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n+1}) $$

Thus, $$ x_n=C_1+C_2(-\frac{1}{2})^n $$

where $ C_1, C_2 $ are constants depending on $ a_1, a_2 $.

I  did not understand  how $x_n=C_1+C_2(-\frac{1}{2})^n $  comes ?

Comment: Do you know how to solve recurrence relations?

Comment: im weak  in maths @Mattos.. i know little bit about recurrence relations

Comment: Can it be proved by induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *"homogeneous second order recurrence with constant coefficients"*, which has the general shape
$$ax_{n+2}  + bx_{n+1} + cx_n = 0,$$
for some given constants $a,b,c$.

According to the general theory of homogeneous second order recurrence with constant coefficients, if the associated *characteristic equation* $ar^2 + br+c=0$ has two distinct roots $r_1, r_2$, the general solution to the recurrence is $$x_n = C_1 r_1^n + C_2 r_2^n$$

where $C_1, C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

In your case, you have $$2x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} - x_n =0,$$ so the characteristic equation is $2r^2 - r-1=0$, which has roots $r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = -1/2$. Thus according to the theory, the general solution is $$x_n = C_1 \cdot 1^n + C_2 (-1/2)^n= C_1 + C_2(-1/2)^n.$$

Have a read of [this document](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf) for example for more information on solving these sorts of recurrences.

Comment: thanks u so much  @ Minus one -12